# Create Object with filled variables and without any setter or constructors

Tags: java, class, object, gson

I want to understand why it is possible to create and fill an object that only got private variables and an overwritten constructor.

Code example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\"id\":\"123546\"}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Participant p = gson.fromJson(json, Participant.class);

        System.out.println(p.getId());
    }

}

public class Participant {

    private int id;

    public Participant() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

It prints "123546" correctly.

The gson.fromJson Method has following signature: `<T> T: fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT)` 
http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: Because reflection is a security hole you can drive a truck through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson, like many other JSON parser/generator libraries, uses reflection to populate fields, either directly or through methods.

Through [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) you can access public **and** non-public members of a class and modify them (fields) or invoke them (methods and constructors).

Your starting point should be the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class, which provides methods to retrieve the `Field`s, `Method`s, and `Constructor`'s of a class.

Gson uses the `Class` object you provide, `Participant.class`, to find out all the fields it needs to populate. It parses the JSON and (attempts to) maps them, one by one.